# Rollup status from task to story to feature in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

Are there any extensions that let you rollup issue status across a hierarchy?

For example, if I have a story where all it's tasks go to Resolved, then the story is set automatically to Resolved?

Likewise, if I have a story where at least one of the tasks go to Active, the story is set to Active, then the story is set to Active?

Ideally, it would do this across a hierarchy, from task, to story, to feature, etc.

Currently, I don't see any extensions that do this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try TFS [Aggregator (Web Service)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-web-service). If you or your team have experience with C#, you may try the console project that I`ve developed: [Automation of state changing](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/automation-of-state-changing-for-azure-devops-work-items-based-on-states-of-child-work-items/).

Comment: Was going to respond with the same answer. Linked logic like that isn't native so you are right on